# Graphviz arrow pointing to another

Tags: graphviz, dot

From the box there will be an arrow pointing to another arrow's tail then position the diamond like that. I've been trying to use the pos attribute but it's not working. Is this possible in Graphviz?

I've been trying to adjust the shapes to another position but no luck in doing so. I've attached the image on the link.

```
digraph {

  SlowJobID [label="Slow Job ID" shape=rectangle color=black]
  FastJobID [label="Fast Job ID" shape=rectangle color=black]
  KnownIssue [label="Known Issue?" shape=diamond]
  Interpret [label="Interpret Timing Details by expanding Timing Tab in Google Admin" shape=rect]
  Review [label="Review existing OMGs for BigQuery" shape=rectangle]
  Long [label="Long creation time?" shape=diamond]

  node[ shape = square ];
  { rank = same; SlowJobID FastJobID}
  { rank = same; KnownIssue Review}

  SlowJobID -> FastJobID [arrowhead=none label= "                                   "];
  SlowJobID -> KnownIssue [arrowhead=none];
  KnownIssue -> Interpret [label="    No "];
  KnownIssue -> Review [label="Yes       "];
  Interpret -> Long  
  

  
}
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. Also show a mockup of what you would like to have.

Comment: I've uploaded the sample and what I did so far.

Comment: Please don't add code as an image but add it verbatim (either wit the use of the `{}` of the edit line, encapsulateting it in a pair of ` ``` ` or indenting all the code with 4 spaces).

Comment: Thank you! Finally formatted the code. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot relate the given image with the image I get when running your code / what you want to achieve. Maybe you should also have a look at https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/

Comment: To get the appearance of an edge pointing to another edge, create a node [shape=point] and use it as head for one edge & tail for the next.